# Running Gradle on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle

I am having a problem running gradle on ubuntu 13.10, which I am assuming is the root of the issue.

I installed `gradle` using the below command

```
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

I am getting an error when running the command `gradle -version`:

```
gradle -version

/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jni/libnative-platform-curses.so: undefined symbol: tgetent
```

I am using java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

I'm not sure what else to do. I tried different versions of java, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you installed Gradle?

Comment: Maybe try installing `libncurses5-dev`; from what I've found online that should contain tgetent.

Comment: @Vidya I have added the command I used above

Comment: Hm... Maybe `ncurses-term` and/or `libterm-query-perl` will help?

Comment: Never done it with apt-get. I just manually download and unzip. Then I define the directory as GRADLE_HOME and add it to my PATH. http://www.gradle.org/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the above problem with advice from Vidya, manually adding gradle into the system allow gradle to correctly work.

Answer (score 11):

I've come up with the patch to the Makefile for libnative-platform-jni.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libnative-platform-java
apt-get source libnative-platform-java
cd libnative-platform-java-0.3~rc2/
```

Apply this patch:

```
--- Makefile.orig   2013-11-20 10:42:54.599476939 -0800
+++ Makefile    2013-11-20 10:43:04.879476606 -0800
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $^

 $(ODIR)/libnative-platform-curses.so: $(OBJ_CURSES)
-   $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -lcurses -shared -o $@ $^
+   $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $^ -lcurses

 $(JCLASSESDIR)/%.class: javafiles-list
  mkdir -p $(JCLASSESDIR)
```

Run:

```
dpkg-source --commit
dpkg-buildpackage
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i libnative-platform-jni_0.3~rc2-2_amd64.deb
```

Test with

```
gradle -v
```

See my comment here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gradle/+bug/1238322/comments/4

Update:
You may want to checkout the ppa here https://launchpad.net/~cwchien/+archive/gradle since gradle 1.4 is pretty old.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 13.10. Since 14.04 has been released now, you might consider upgrading: Gradle works perfectly on [Ubuntu 14.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/). However, I'd recommend downloading gradle from the [gradle website](http://www.gradle.org/) since the official repos still only have gradle 1.4

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and [this bug keeps happening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set).

Answer (score 3):

> /home/stens/src/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jni/libnative-platform-curses.so: undefined symbol: tgetent

This is the easiest workaround I've found ... download the deb here

https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libnative-platform-jni/download

then install using

```
sudo dpkg -i libnative-platform-jni_0.11-5_amd64.deb
```

now gradle works ... Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: This broke my Gradle installation (at least). Perhaps it would be a good to know which libnative-platform-jni version to download.