# Gradle finds wrong JAVA_HOME even though it's correctly set

Tags: java, linux, gradle, environment-variables

When trying to run gradle, I get the following error:

```
# gradle

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

However, when I check the JAVA_HOME variable I get:

```
# echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

My JAVA_HOME is defined in .bashrc and I have double checked that it is set as the source.

Running `java -version` also confirms that JAVA_HOME is set correctly and is on the PATH.

```
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I have also checked that `/usr/bin/java` symlinks to `/etc/alternatives/java` which in turn correctly symlinks to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java`

Additionally I've checked that there are no duplicate JAVA_HOME definitions in `.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`.

So my question is how/why does Gradle find `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`, and more importantly how do I point it to the correct directory?

Other programs which require the JDK work fine, so I think its a Gradle issue. I've also tried reinstalling Gradle which made no difference.

I'm running 64bit Xubuntu (Ubuntu 13.10 base)

Comment: Please provide the full error output. As it stands, it's not clear where the message comes from. Also, do you have a `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` directory or symlink? And how did you install Gradle?

Comment: I've updated the Q, but that pretty much is the full error output. There is no `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` dir. Installed with apt (apt-get install gradle)

Comment: The Gradle start script doesn't need `JAVA_HOME` to be set. If `JAVA_HOME` is set, the script uses `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` to run Gradle. Otherwise, it uses `java` (i.e. `java` has to be on the `PATH`). Perhaps the (third-party) apt package uses a modified start script.

Comment: Yea looks like whatever ppa I got the binary from had hard coded and exported the JAVA_HOME to `usr/lib/jvm/defult-java`. Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you do `source ~/.bashrc`, or reboot your machine after setting JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Just do export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/correct/java/version

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Turns out that the particular Gradle binary I downloaded from the Ubuntu 13.10 repository *itself* tries to export JAVA_HOME. Thanks to [Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516433/lucas) for suggesting this.

`/usr/bin/gradle` line 70:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

Commenting this line out solves the problem, and Gradle finds the correct path to the Java binary.

If you just download the binary from their [website](http://www.gradle.org/downloads) it does not have this problem, 
It's an issue with the Ubuntu repo version. [There also seem to be some other issues with 13.10 version.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522020/running-gradle-on-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: The gradle package appears to install the jdk to this location, at least on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with only the default repositories. I did this on an Ubuntu VM that did not have Java, snapshotted it first, apt-get install gradle (which installs almost 400 packages), and it installed java to /usr/lib/jvm... reverted snapshot, no /usr/lib/jvm. I was testing the theory of gradle script exporting JAVA_HOME and indeed it does, as you found.

Comment: Gradle doesn't do this. The ppa is provided by someone else, and so you'd have to ask them. In general, I would recommend to bootstrap Gradle via the Gradle Wrapper, rather than installing it via a package manager.

Comment: I updated the answer to make it clearer that the Ubuntu repo version is the problem, not Gradle itself.

Comment: Thank you, i search for over an hour for an solution to this problem. Thanks for this post, it solves my problem on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Way to solve your own problem (and mine simultaneously)! It's a shame that this question is a year old and the Gradle script in the repository hasn't been updated to fix this.

Comment: Awesome. Problem is still around with Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: We also now have  sdkman (sdkman.io) to manage download/versions of gradle and other JVM sdk's.

Comment: the newer version of android studio also has the same issue. but in a different way. it seems like they have resolved the `export` issue. but we have to call `sudo ./gradlew install` to get it work sometimes.

Comment: I faced same issue. But in my GRADLE_HOME/bin/gradle file this line was not present - `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`. Hence I couldn't figure out where does it pick the wrong one from.
I am using gradle version 2.13 on RHEL 7.3. So to resolve this issue, I added the line `export JAVA_HOME=/correct/path/to/java` in GRADLE_HOME/bin/gradle file.

Comment: also i put this to my `~/.bashrc` to not enter this command everytime after reload

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`

Answer (score 51):

add a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

Comment: @Nar could you please provide the installation path of JAVA

Comment: Thank you for answer but path of JAVA does not matter because gradle script overrides path as said James http://stackoverflow.com/a/22309017/1679348

Comment: Worked just fine for me. Given the name (*default-java*), I'd say this is a fairly sensible approach.

Comment: In my  opinion this is much better solution than changing Gradle files. (And yes, it works for me just fine)

Comment: this is very fragile and will break once java gets upgraded to next release

Answer (score 26):

Solution is to make JAVA_HOME == dir above bin where javac lives as in

```
type javac

javac is /usr/bin/javac   # now check if its just a symlink

ls -la /usr/bin/javac 

/usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac   # its a symlink so check again

ls -la /etc/alternatives/javac  # now check if its just a symlink

/etc/alternatives/javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

OK so finally found the bin above actual javac so do this

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

above can be simplified and generalized to

```
which javac >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "ERROR: no 'javac' command could be found in your PATH"
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac)  )))
```

Answer (score 14):

For me this error was due to the reason **Gradle** as installed as **sudo** and I was trying as default user to run Gradle.

Try:

```
sudo gradle -version
```

or

```
sudo gradle -v
```

Answer (score 8):

Did you `export` your `JAVA_HOME`?  Without export, the setting will not be propagated to the commands started inside of that shell.  Also, `java -version` does not use `JAVA_HOME`, rather it uses the first `java` found in your path.  Make sure your `.bashrc` looks something like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home
export JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Yes, its defined in .bashrc as `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` (slightly different syntax but I assume its the same)

Comment: @JamesBarnett, could the `gradle` command itself be setting that variable?  Perhaps the person who installed `gradle` created a wrapper script that set environment variables before starting the application.  When using tomcat, it is not uncommon for the `catalina.sh` (which is the startup script) to call out to a `setenv.sh` to set up environment variables which may include `JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 8):

In my Ubuntu, I have a headache for 2 days on this issue.

Step 1. Type on the terminal `whereis java`
then it will display something like this

```
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Step 2. Take note of the path: 
 `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

exclude the `bin/java`

your JAVA_HOME = `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: Key here is to exclude /bin/java

Answer (score 7):

Try installing latest version of `gradle`,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gradle
```

If we install from ubuntu repo, it will install the old version , (for me it was gradle 1.4). In older version, it sets java home from gradle as `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`. Latest version don't have this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue when I run the following command on Ubuntu:

```
ionic build android
```

To solve this issue, I did the following steps:

```
ln -sf /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

Add JAVA_HOME to /etc/environment:

```
vi /etc/environment
```

Add:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
```

After saving, read it:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Finally, you can run build command.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but I didnt find export command in line 70 in gradle file for the latest version 2.13, but I understand a silly mistake there, that is following,

If you don't find line 70 with export command in gradle file in your gradle folder/bin/ , then check your ~/.bashrc, if you find  `export JAVA_HOME==/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`, then remove `/bin/java` from this line, like `JAVA_HOME==/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`, and it in path>>> instead of this `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:JAVA_HOME/`, it will be `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:JAVA_HOME/bin/java`. Then run `source ~/.bashrc`.

The reason is, if you check your gradle file, you will find in line 70 (if there's no export command) or in line 75,

> ```
> JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
>     fi
>     if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
>         die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME
> ```
>
> That means  `/bin/java` is already there, so it needs to be substracted from `JAVA_HOME` path.

That happened in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I have tested this on Manjaro Linux. Should work on other Disto too.

You need to include whole java-jdk dir instead of just java/bin for java env var.

For example, instead of:

`export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-14.0.2/bin` #change path according to your jdk location
`PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME`

use this:

`export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-14.0.2/`    #change path according to your jdk location
`PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME`

then run the gradle command it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can also go to the bin folder inside your gradle installation folder and correct the JAVA_HOME parameter in gradle.bat file.
In my case, my JAVA_HOME was set to c:\Program files\java\bin
The JAVA_HOME in gradle.bat was set to %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe.

I corrected the JAVA_HOME in gradle.bat and it worked.

Thank you!!!

Comment: its now 2019 and this is STILL an issue!  Except its slightly different and the variable at fault is now "set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe" - remove the bin part from here to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Before running the command try entering:

```
export JAVA_HOME="path_to_java_home"
```

Where `path_to_java_home` is the folder where your `bin/java` is.

If java is properly installed you can find it's location, by using the command:

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

Don't forget to remove `bin/java` from the end of the path while putting it into `JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 2):

For me an explicit set on the arguments section of the external tools configuration in Eclipse was the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

Create a symbolic link to the default-java directory.

You can find your java directory by

```
readlink -f $(which java) 
# outputs: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
# Remove the last `/bin/java` and use it in above symbolic link command.
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if you explained what this command does and why it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with this too. It said wrong directory when it was correct. So I just created a local variable with the name of JAVA_HOME omitting the final /bin/java. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your GRADLE_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment are set properly then check your JDK directory and make sure you have ***java.exe*** file under below path.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin
```

As error mentioned in gradle.bat file

```
:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.
```

It is not able to locate your java installation. So find and set

> java.exe

under `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` if everything is correct.

This works for me (my account got disabled by client and their admin has removed java.exe from my directory.)

Comment: I was able to solve the described issue by deleting the gradle wrapper from my project directory and re-initializing it with a newer system gradle (7.4.2). The issue was the 'goto init'. There are two lines which changed to 'goto execute'.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows] As already said, it looks like .bat -file tries to find java.exe from `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe` so it doesn't find it since `bin` is repeated twice in path.
Remov that extra `/bin` from gradle.bat.

[image: Gradle]

Answer (score 0):

In my dockercontainer (being minimal the problem of not finding java) was, that "which" was not installed. Comipling a project using gradlew used which in ./gradlew to find java
Installing which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding below lines in build.gradle solved my issue .

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

Answer (score 0):

#ISSUE:*GradleException: javaConfig.targetVersion is Java 8, but the environment variable JAVA8_HOME does not exist*

I think this is how you fix it in IntelliJ. I've run into it a couple times as I choose "Launch in New Window" for a new project but I haven't written down the steps yet.
1.File -> Project Structure. Project Settings / Project. Make sure Project SDK and Project language level are correct.
2.Preferences. Build, Execution, Deployment / Build Tools / Gradle. Make sure Gradle JVM is correct.
You may have to restart IntelliJ after this.

---

NOW it SOLVED THE ISSUE

---

> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 22s

---