# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - java8/gradle, error with JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: gradle, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install gradle and but I keep getting the error:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin

When I type in `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin

and that same path is specified in `.bashrc` as well so I really have no idea what is happening. I tried to google this problem but the closest issue I could find to my own was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set) but I don't think I'm having quite the same problem and the solutions don't seem to work anyway.

I installed java by following [this tutorial](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/) and I installed gradle first by trying [these steps](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-gradle-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivatives/) and when that didn't work, I removed gradle and tried it [this way](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/03/30/install-gradle-on-ubuntu-linux/). Both times I got the same error message whenever I typed in `gradle`.

I've only been using Ubuntu for a few months so I'm still learning the OS and how to use it. Any help troubleshooting the issue here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set JAVA_HOME to location without bin folder:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Comment: run the command:  sudo gedit ~/.bashrc , look for the JAVA_HOME variable definition, edit it like @Gondy's advice and it will work.

Comment: I've tried that and now I get the same error with the new path: ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun

Comment: You have written you have tried to install Oracle JDK 8. Why are you pointing to java 6 sun?

Comment: I didn't set the path myself, I used ` sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default` from the tutorial I linked to in the question. I'll see if I can find the java8 path and change it to that...

Comment: Okay so I found the java8 folder and set my path to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. Everything seems to be working, `gradle -version` doesn't give an error at the very least so thank you for your help!