# libGDX setup allows me to use Java 8 which crashes in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I'm new to java/android so I'm hoping this is a pretty easy thing to solve.

I've used [libGDX's setup](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html) to create a project, which I then imported to Android Studio. I didn't know the [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) interface was only available to Java 8, and used it in the core module, which as far as I understand, it compiles into a library that is shared by all android/html/desktop/ios versions of the game. The desktop version runs fine (I have Java 8 installed), but my android app crashes with a `NoClassDefFoundError` error (BTW, the error message was showing the name of classes that I wrote, and not `Supplier`, but the error disappeared as soon as I removed every reference to `Supplier` and came back when I added them, so apparently the error message doesn't show the actual problem class).

If I try to use `Supplier` in my android module, it won't even let me import the class, so it knows it doesn't support that Java version, but it'll happily let me use it in the core module without any warning. I'm sure removing references to `Supplier` will solve the problem, but this fix may cause runtime errors later on if I inadvertently use any Java 8 features, so not a good way to solve it.

I don't know where in the project is it set to use Java 8, and there seem to be a bunch of .gradle, .xml and .iml files which apparently are all related to configuration. Here is my `build.gradle` file in the core module:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```

Android studio shows the `sourceCompatibility = 1.6` line grayed out and says "Assignment is not used" when I hover over it. So that may be part of the problem.

My `core.iml` file contains this line too:

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_6" inherit-compiler-output="false">
```

Also, here is the `core` section in the root `build.gradle` file:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```

So, what should I change to prevent it from letting me use Java 8 in my core project?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `targetCompatibility` attribute with `sourceCompatibility` in gradle to target your `java` version.

```
    allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}
```

Also need to check `java` default path in `gradle.properties` file with version your project is use.

You need to check [Can’t build Java 1.8 even with proper Java version in use](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cant-build-java-1-8-even-with-proper-java-version-in-use/2461) and [Gradle finds wrong JAVA_HOME even though it's correctly set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set) to get more idea about set `java` compile version gradle.

Answer (score 0):

As of JDK 9 (**) you will probably have better luck with the `--release` option (see [What is the --release flag in the Java 9 compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102787/what-is-the-release-flag-in-the-java-9-compiler)) rather than the `--source` and/or `--target` options.  The release option will ensure that the code is compiled in an environment with the correct (older) APIs, and that the generated bytecode will run in older environments too.

In Gradle this is exposed as `compileJava.options.release`, as in:

```
compileJava.options.release = 8
```

to build source and bytecode for a JDK1.8 compatible environment.

See the Gradle documentation for more details:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_cross_compilation

(**) See the [Warning](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_cross_compilation) in the Gradle documentation that a bug in JDK 9 means JDK 10 is effectively required.