# Exporting a package from system module is not allowed with --release

Tags: java, javac, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I have the following program:

**module-info.java**

```
module a {
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sun.nio.ByteBuffered.class);
    }
}
```

This program successfully compiles with the `--add-exports` option:

```
> javac --add-exports java.base/sun.nio=a module-info.java Main.java
```

However, when I add the `--release` argument, it fails:

```
> javac --add-exports java.base/sun.nio=a --release 9 module-info.java Main.java
error: exporting a package from system module java.base is not allowed with --release
1 error
```

Basically, these two commands are equivalent. So why is the latter one forbidden?

Also, since IDEA passes the `--release` argument to javac, this makes the development in IDEA impossible if my project needs an internal API.

I'm using JDK 9+178.

Comment: @Tavo That question is about `--add-exports`. My question is about the combination of `--add-exports` and `--release` which makes it completely different.

Comment: As correctly said by Michael Easter, this combination of options have been forbidden in javac, so it is now for IDEA devs to adjust their compiler invocation. I've filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176994 - hopefully, it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov Thank you for the bug report! I wanted to do it but had no chance and time.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov I think this is fixed in IDEA. I just tried 2017.2.5 and everything worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Due to [JDK-8178152](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178152) `--release` cannot be used in combination with `--add-exports`, `--add-reads`, and `--patch-module`.

Quoting JDK-8178152:

> The overall proposal here is to get make --release 9 work consistently
> between JDK 9 and the (anticipated) JDK 10, even at the cost of a
> possible different behavior of commands like:
> `$ <jdk9>/javac Test.java`
> `$ <jdk9>/javac --release 9 Test.java`

Also:

> Which should be acceptable, given the intents of --release - allow to
> compile code using supported APIs for the given JDK release.
>
> In particular the proposal is to:
>
> [edit]
>
> -prevents use of --add-exports, -add-reads and --patch-module for system modules in combination with --release (any version)

[Here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/langtools/rev/77a2d6c1f321) is the file diff that contains:

> exporting a package from system module {0} is not allowed with
> --release

I can't comment on the rationale but from the above quote, it pertains to allowing JDK 9 to work consistently with JDK 10.

Comment: So, Java 10 will not allow exporting of packages from platform modules?

Comment: Java 10 will not allow _the combination_ of `--release` and exporting of packages from platform modules. I'm not sure that we can conclude that only `--add-exports` is not available in Java 10. That is a separate question. Please accept the answer that best answers your original question.

Comment: The answer is correct. The idea of `--release` is to allow to compile against *public* API of a *specific* release, signatures of which are recorded and bundled with javac. On the other hand, `--add-exports` and its friends allow to change *private* (as well as public) API of the *current* release. To allow the combination of these options javac would need to have a record of all packages and classes of all releases.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov I think that's the case. --release is replacing --source --target and --bootclasspath parameter which was required for cross compilation (e.g. compiling to java6 with jdk9): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102787/what-is-the-release-flag-in-the-java-9-compiler

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov would you be open to considering moving that from a comment to an answer? Please tag me for a bounty to it once you do so.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using IntelliJ, there is a better solution.
Just uncheck the "Use '--release' option" checkbox in the Java compiler settings
[image]

Answer (score 12):

If you are using IntelliJ idea, try checking your Java compiler settings:

Go to the File menu -> [Settings] -> [Build, Execution, Deployment] -> [Java Compiler] and check the setting "Project bytecode version". I got a similar error ("exporting a package from system module java.datatransfer is not allowed with --release") when using JDK 11 while this value was still set to version 9. Setting it to 11 fixed the problem for me.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I cleared the **Use '--release' option**, IDEA doesn't add this option to the compiler and compilation is successful.

Answer (score 9):

use `-target` & `-source` instead:

```
-target 11 -source 11
```

Comment: This is not a universal solution. --release has special meaning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102787/what-is-the-release-flag-in-the-java-9-compiler

Answer (score 2):

Go to the File menu -> [Settings] -> [Build, Execution, Deployment] -> [Java Compiler]
and select your JDK version. (Make sure it is higher than JDK 11)

[image: See the image below]

Comment: This doesn't work.  The compiler is (correctly) rejecting the flag to build for a target JRE while making use of a JDK-only package; it has nothing to do with the bytecode that would have been generated if the compiler had actually compiled it.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, uncheck the --release from the **project properties** and not from general settings

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are using InetlliJ Idea do this setting:
Go to the File menu -> [Settings] -> [Build, Execution, Deployment] -> [Java Compiler] and select your JDK version and sometimes this is empty so insert the java version like [if you use 11] and save, 
Then compile the program and run.

Comment: This does not address OP's problem; IntelliJ _is_ successfully attempting the compile via the configured JDK.  The compiler is (correctly) rejecting the attempt to build for a JRE target while making use of a JDK-only package.