# how to use jdk.internal.misc.Signal in java11

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

I've got a class that uses `jdk.internal.misc.Signal`.
In `module-info.java` there is `requires jdk.unsupported`.

If I try to compile this I get:

```
[ERROR] MyClass.java:[28,20] package jdk.internal.misc is not visible
[ERROR]   (package jdk.internal.misc is declared in module java.base, which does not export it to module MyModule)
```

Then if I add `<arg>--add-exports</arg><arg>java.base/jdk.internal.misc=MyModule</arg>` 
to maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1 I get:

```
[ERROR] exporting a package from system module java.base is not allowed with --release
```

Then if I remove `<release>11</release>` I get:

```
Fatal error compiling: warning: source release 11 requires target release 11
```

I've the feeling that I'm missing something important or maybe it is just a bug?
I'm using maven 3.6.3 and openjdk 11.0.2.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370178/exporting-a-package-from-system-module-is-not-allowed-with-release

Comment: Where is it getting source release from?  Just avoid screwing around with release altogether.

Comment: thanks @SeanF looks like I should use source/target instead of release

Comment: When you removed <release> but kept <source> maven defaulted <target> to 1.6. I assume you had source=11 hence the error: It's not possible to compile java11 sources to java6 bytecode.

Comment: @SeanF it's not a duplicate. The question you linked is about java.nio and this one is about Signal and SignalHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jdk.internal.misc.Signal` is in `java.base` module. If you take a look inside its `module-info.java` file you will notice this:

```
    exports jdk.internal.misc to
        (...)
        jdk.unsupported;
```

However `jdk.unsupported` contains `sun.misc.Signal` which is the original pre-Java 9 class for handling signals.

In general usage of classes in `.internal.` packages is a bad practice because they are not part of public API.

Instead I would suggest to use `sun.misc.Signal` with `requires jdk.unsupported` module clause until there is a `@Deprecated` annotation with information which API should be used instead.

BTW. This is a great example how JPMS helps with hiding internal implementation details of a library (in this case JDK) from un/intended usage.

Answer (score 2):

fixed by changing `<release>11</release>` into `<target>11</target>` in my `pom.xml`:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
```

Comment: For reference here's a [JDK-8178152](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8178152) explaining the rationale. So _the intent of `--release M` is to only have **public supported API of release `M`**_, meaning any modifications like `--add-exports`, `-add-reads`, `--patch-module`, `--upgrade-module-path` are unsupported, and as such raise the error if modifications and `--release` flags are used together.