# java compilation : source, target and release supported versions

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I may do some cross-compilations for legacy projects and I noticed with recent JDKs that we are limited to some specific versions for the `source`, `target` and `release` JVM arguments.
How to get the supported versions for these arguments ?

Comment: @Robin Topper I agree that it could be better.  In fact I just created this post to reduce the length of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p/38883073#38883073 that becomes bloat. And as this information is not present in any question of SO and that I consider it useful I would not like to just erase the information.

Comment: If you want to make it a proper question, you should at least mention that it has something to do with Maven. Question is a bit flimsy at the moment and doesn't seem to fit the answer

Comment: it doesn't have any relationship with Maven. The original question was broad and Maven is just a wrapper of javac. So to explain things I had to dig down in javac.

Answer (score 12):

Indeed the supported values depend on the major JDK version used.
You can find the information on the `javac` documentation of the respective major JDK versions (the links are referenced below).

Some general notes about these arguments :

- The `source` and the `target` version in the Maven configuration should not be superior to the JDK version used.
  A older version of the JDK cannot compile with a more recent version since it doesn't know its specification.
- Beware : while a recent JDK can accept as `source` compilation an older Java version,  it doesn't mean that you can select as `source` any supported recent version and as `target` any older version that is documented as supported (see below).
  In indeed, Java versions may introduce new features that were not designed to be compatible with older Java version at compile time/run time.
  For example a JDK 11 can compile classes with 8 as `source` compiler version. By choosing also 8 as `target` compiler version, compilation will pass.
  But if you change your mind and that you want to compile with 11 as `source` and 8 as `target`, compilation will fail.
  That is not always explicitly documented in the javac documentation.
- The `release` argument exists from Java 9.
- As the `source` and the `target` are the same, the `release` argument  should be favored over `source` and `target`. It is shorter to specify and it ensures a better cross compilation compatibility and whatever even if you don't do cross compilations, it will not hurt.
  For more explanations please refer to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103038/270371).

**source/target/release supported versions :**

[**For Java 7**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html)

- supported `source` :

> 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), and 1.7 (also 7).

- supported `target` :

> 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), and
> 1.7 (also 7).

[**For Java 8**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

- supported `source` :

> 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), 1.7 (also 7), and 1.8 (also 8).

- supported `target` :

> 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), 1.7
> (also 7), and 1.8 (also 8).

[**For Java 9**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627)

- supported `source` :

> 1.6 (also 6), 1.7 (also 7), 1.8 (also 8), and 9.

- supported `target` :

> 1.6 (also 6), 1.7 (also 7), 1.8 (also 8) and 9.

- supported `release` :

> 6, 7, 8, and 9.

[**For Java 10**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627)

- supported `source` :

> 1.6 (also 6), 1.7 (also 7), 1.8 (also 8), 9, and 10.

- supported `target` :

> 1.6 (also 6), 1.7 (also 7), 1.8 (also 8), 9 and 10.

- supported `release` :

> 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10.

[**For Java 11**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9)

- supported `source/target/release` :

> 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11.

You could have more details in [the javac documentation for JDK 1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), [JDK 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627), [JDK 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627) and [JDK 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9)