# A JNI error occurs when I switch from jdk 11 to jdk 1.8.0_191

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-7

So using JDK 11 everything works fine. I had to switch to an older version of jdk to garentee total compatibility whith all other technologies while I am learning JEE. So I downloaded jdk1.8.0_191 and installed it. I switched the jdk from Window > Java > Installed JREs in my Eclipse. My program is a normal Java project tries to write in mysql database. Once I switch and run the program I get this pop up error:

[image: pop up error message]

and my console display the next errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/exemple/ProgrammTest has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Any help?

Comment: You need to compile you'r code with Java 1.8 backward compatibility option. I.e. `javac -source=1.8 -target=1.8`.

Comment: @VictorGubin even better: [`--release 8`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103038/2711488).