# Can javac 11 compile binaries/jars that will run on a java 8 JVM?

Tags: java

Can javac 11 compile binaries/jars that will run on a java 8 JVM?

If so, with what flags?

Will setting gradle source compatibility to 11 and target compatibility to 8 work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but not with source=11 and target=8; only source=8 target=8 will work. You can't use any java features introduced in java9, 10, or 11.

On the command line, the javac option you're looking for is `-release 8` (which is like `-source 8 -target 8` but shorter and better).

Comment: [`--release 8` is not _just_ shorthand for `-source 8 -target 8`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102787/what-is-the-release-flag-in-the-java-9-compiler).

Comment: "(which is *like* `-source 8 -target 8` but shorter, **and better**)"