# Maven Compiler Error After Upgrading to JDK11 on Jenkins(Threading Issue?)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-plugin, java-11

Upgraded to Java 11 for our test framework, and things run fine locally(confirmed by several team members).  But when attempting to run on Jenkins I'm getting compiler errors that seem to be thread related.

Not sure what could be causing the issue only in Jenkins, but not when run from IntelliJ.

Jenkins version: 2.164.1

Maven Integration plugin: 3.2

POM file looks like:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11.0.3</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <karate.version>0.9.3</karate.version>
</properties>
```

```
<build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Error in Jenkins:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project karate-archetype: Execution default-testCompile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile failed: multiple points -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project karate-archetype: Execution default-testCompile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile failed: multiple points
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main (Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch (Maven35Main.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run (Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call (InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-testCompile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile failed: multiple points
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main (Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch (Maven35Main.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run (Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call (InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
    at jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString (FloatingDecimal.java:1914)
    at jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble (FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble (Double.java:543)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf (Double.java:506)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.preparePaths (TestCompilerMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:792)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.execute (TestCompilerMojo.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main (Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch (Maven35Main.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run (Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call (InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: one correction `<java.version>11.0.3</java.version>` should be `<java.version>11</java.version>`

Comment: Tried, didn't recognize the java version as valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed this for me was removing the `source` and `target` lines in my pom and replacing them with `release`.  See explanation here:
[What is the --release flag in the Java 9 compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102787/what-is-the-release-flag-in-the-java-9-compiler)

Comment: Just wondering, did you still use `<release>11.0.3</release>` and it worked?

Comment: No.  Per the explanation given in the other stackoverflow thread I linked to, the release tag requires that you only specify the major version you wish to use, and Maven will automatically pull in the latest release.  Not sure if 11.0.3 would have worked, but that doesn't seem to be the design of the `<release>` tag.

Comment: Indeed and that is where `<souce>11</source>` and `<target>11</target>` should work with maven as well. Afterall *[`--release N` is equivalent to `-source N -target N -bootclasspath <bootclasspath-from-N>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103038/1746118)*

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source for the maven compiler plugin at the line given in your stacktrace

`at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.preparePaths (TestCompilerMojo.java:313)`

https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/a130a260099c4ade3c2bb749ca1eae1bd6b9c11e/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/TestCompilerMojo.java#L313

You will see it uses `Double.valueOf(getTarget())`. It expects `getTarget()` to be a parsable double.

`11.0.3` is not a valid double as it has two decimal points. `<java.version>11</java.version>` would be valid. It also has to be a target `javac` recognizes.

```
C:\Users\Adam\jython>javac -target 11.0.3
error: invalid target release: 11.0.3
```

Perhaps the full maven invocation is not happening in IntelliJ, or some other setting is overriding. You should be able to reproduce on the local command line, though.

Comment by @Naman on the question points the same way, more tersely.