# Does IntelliJ not utilize Maven's <release> for target byte code level?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3, javac

I just found out, that IntelliJ behaves very peculiarly when configuring the maven-compiler-plugin with `<release>` only:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <release>14</release>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As a result after reloading the Maven project, in the 'Java Compiler' preferences, it displays target bytecode level `8` instead of the expected `14`. I guess it was inferred because the modules didn't use any Java 14 features, yet.

see preferences screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqpKV.jpg

In comparison, when adding `<source>` and `<target>` the IDE configures its own configuration, correctly.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>14</source>
    <target>14</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

see preferences screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqpKV.jpg

As far as I understand it, the javac `--release` option is slightly more reliable than just defining `-source` and `-target` because it additionally sets the `-bootclasspath` option to the correct level (double-checked with [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103038)). So it seems to me that relying on this option exclusively is a better practice.

Is there another configuration step that I would have to execute in order to make IntelliJ set up the preferences, correctly, without declaring the older parameters?

Comment: If you use in in child pom then it couldn't override settings from parent pom: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-199818

Comment: I indeed got a parent-pom that configures the plugin in its <pluginManagement>, but I override that config in my child-pom with the newer Java version. So I assumed that should trigger IntelliJ to read the property correctly but it doesn't. /headscratch but thanks for linking the ticket, maybe I can get more out of that and find a solution : )

Answer (score 1):

I investigated that issue a little closer and found out that somewhere in one of the parent poms the maven-compiler-plugin was added to the `<pluginManagement>` with a maven-property that got never set for the configuration.

This seemed to have caused IntelliJ to infer by language level even though I overwrote the plugin configuration in the child-pom.

I guess that's acceptable behaviour because if the parent pom is faulty, IntelliJ shouldn't try too hard to figure out stuff on its own to just cause more confusion.