# Gradle uses wrong JAVA_HOME when running cordova android build

Tags: cordova, gradle, jvm

**Update:**
I tried removing every trace of java openjdk, installing Oracle Java 8, and setting up my environment variables again but still no bueno. So after I did `source ~/.bashrc` I closed all terminals, logged out, and viola, all fixed. What a hassle though.

**OP:**
I came across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set) that seems to deal with the same issue I am having. Unfortunately, I didn't have the line `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` in my `usr/bin/gradle` file.

My error says `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre`

But `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre`

I tried creating a symlink between the real JAVA_HOME and the one gradle keeps trying to use but the one gradle is trying to use isn't real so I get the error `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre': No such file or directory`

I tried digging around the gradlew file and found what I think may be the offending code but I'm not 100% sure how it works and any time I edit the file and then execute `cordova run android` all my changes are wiped away.

This is the bit of code I found in gradlew:

```
# Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
        # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
    if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
        die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
    fi
else
    JAVACMD="java"
    which java >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
fi
```

My full error report:

```
Running command: /home/grant/Development/Projects/ACA/hooks/after_prepare/icons_and_splashscreens.js /home/grant/Development/Projects/ACA
Running command: /home/grant/Development/Projects/ACA/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js /home/grant/Development/Projects/ACA
ANDROID_HOME=/home/grant/Development/Android
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
No target specified, deploying to device '05157df5a3d39408'.

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /home/grant/Development/Projects/ACA/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/grant/Development/Projects/ACA/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Java home should look like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`, without the 'jre' part.
Secondly, it should be put in the /etc/profile file:

`export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`

`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Is there an advantage to defining JAVA_HOME in `/etc/profile` as opposed to `.bashrc` or `/etc/environment` I have defined both JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME in `.bashrc` and I have added some other things to my path in `/etc/environment`