# gradle Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'

Tags: java, gradle, ghidra

- I'm building ghidra according to the [installation guide](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/master/DevGuide.md).
  Everything goes fine Until I get [here](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/master/DevGuide.md#building-ghidra).
- Once I call `$ gradle buildGhidra` I get the following error:

```
> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'
```

This seems weird because I *do* have java 11:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It turns out that `gradle` *was* after all the one to blame.
- Probably similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set), I upgraded to [gradle-6.7](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-rc-3-bin.zip).
- Then, calling `gradle-6.7 --version`, **without any JAVA_HOME change whatsoever**, I got:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7-rc-3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-09-30 19:16:51 UTC
Revision:     836e96a80625c9c48b612e662e3b13bd2e2f4c3b

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          11.0.8 (Ubuntu 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-48-generic amd64
```

Which probably "proves" gradle is indeed the one to blame

Comment: I think you are right that it was Gradle issue after all. But from the link you gave, it is actually Ubuntu that is to blame. From what I can read, Ubuntu has a custom distribution of Gradle where they change the start-up script to redefine `JAVA_HOME`. (I assume you installed it through the package manager.) When you instead downloaded 6.7-rc-3 from the official servers, you got a vanilla distribution without this weird behavior. I wonder why the Ubuntu folks have done that... :/

Answer (score 33):

I got this problem when trying to build using gradle through Intellij.

In my case I had two JDK's JDK1.8 and JDK 11 installed and configured in Intellij.
For Gradle it was taking JDK1.8 as default JVM.
I solved the issue using below steps :

1. Open Intellij
2. Go to Preferences
3. Go to "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Build Tools" -> Gradle
4. Search for "Gradle JVM". Change it to desired JVM
5. Try to rebuild the app

Answer (score 6):

Gradle uses the java distribution defined in your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable - it does not look at the java executable in your path. So make sure this variable points to a valid JDK 11 path. You can verify if it is set up correctly by running `gradle --version`, e.g.

```
$ echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Work\JDKs\jdk-11.0.8+10


$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-08-10 22:06:19 UTC
Revision:     d119144684a0c301aea027b79857815659e431b9

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          11.0.8 (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.8+10)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

(Notice the JVM part above.)

Comment: OK it's not, it says: `JVM: 1.8.0_265 (Private Build 25.265-b01)` but can I change it now? or should I uninstall gradle and install it again??

Comment: This is not about Gradle but rather your JDK installation. You have to make sure your JAVA_HOME environment variable is set correctly. I see that you are using Ubunto which, depending on how you installed Java, manages this for you. Run `echo $JAVA_HOME` to see what it is set to. If it is wrong, try running `update-java-alternatives -l` to list the Java installations, and `sudo update-java-alternatives -s [NAME]` to set it to a particular version. If this does not work, try looking for the variable in `/etc/environment`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` or similar places.

Comment: No `JAVA_HOME` in any of the mentioned places ... I have absolutely no clue how can gradle find another java version, when I called `update-java-alternatives -l` there was only one (11) java version

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an IDE? Make sure that in your Gradle settings, Gradle is using the same java version as your project, this can be easily configured in Intellij https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-jvm-selection.html#jdk_existing_project

Comment: No, I'm not using an IDE. Everything I do is from terminal

Comment: U can also define the java version in your gradle.properties or build.gradle file (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/12089702)

Answer (score 0):

Changing my agent label in the `Jenkinsfile`, to `openjdk11` fixed this error for me.

```
agent {
    label 'openjdk11'
}
```