# Gradle is showing different JAVA_HOME version that I set

Tags: java, spring, docker, macos, gradle

The Gradle project I'm trying to build is from [this example on GitHub.](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-boot-login-samples/tree/master/mvc-login) (per the README, I'm running the exec.sh script).

I am trying to build a Gradle Docker image on my MacBook Pro (Big Sur v 11.6.6), but as many other SO entries mentioned, I keep getting this common error:

```
> #7 0.301 ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /opt/java/openjdk
> #7 0.301 
> #7 0.301 Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
> #7 0.301 location of your Java installation.
```

However, I've set JAVA_HOME to an entirely different value, and when I echo it on my terminal, I get that correct value:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And

```
/usr/libexec/java_home       
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I've gone through all the SO entries on this, and the solution is usually to set the JAVA_HOME variable to the correct value. However, in this case, I've successfully set that variable.

My shell is:

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

So I added JAVA_HOME to .zshrc as well.

Why, then, does Gradle keep telling me I'm using a different value? I've been Googling this error all today, and have not found this precise situation.

NOTE: I did read [Gradle finds wrong JAVA_HOME even though it's correctly set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set), but that's for Ubuntu, and the suggested fixes didn't work.

I also added a "gradle.properties" to the root of my project and added the following line, but that didn't help either:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The output I get from running "exec.sh" is:

```
sh exec.sh
[+] Building 1.0s (8/8) FINISHED                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 119B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 117B                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/gradle:7.4.2-jdk11      0.6s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/gradle:7.4.2-jdk11@sha256:66e99844e0687a  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 14.03kB                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /tmp                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] ADD . /tmp                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN gradle build                                           0.3s
------
 > [4/4] RUN gradle build:
#8 0.286 
#8 0.286 ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /opt/java/openjdk
#8 0.286 
#8 0.286 Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
#8 0.286 location of your Java installation.
#8 0.286 
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c gradle build]: exit code: 1
Unable to find image 'auth0/[IMAGENAME]:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for auth0/[IMAGENAME], repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I can also confirm that I can run the app *outside* of Docker, so that is where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: would you mind providing full output from exec.sh? BTW, I do believe those code samples won't work in docker env: master branch uses spring boot 2.7.0 which is not compatible with gradle 6.5

Comment: If this is in a Docker context, the Docker image has its own Java installation and its own environment; it sees neither the JDK on your host nor the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable you have set.  Do you have the image's Dockerfile, or any other source code required to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I updated as requested. One thing - I did update the Dockerfile to the below to try and version it correctly:

FROM gradle:7.4.2-jdk11