# Windows 10 Gradle: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid director even though it points to jdk

Tags: java, gradle

trying to run gradle test but I get this error
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin;

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

How do I edit the Java_Home variable so that gradle works?

Comment: Didn't check the docs but I think often JAVA_HOME points to just C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19 and the program adds \bin or \lib or whatever as needed.

Comment: Some other ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set